# how do I get MPI profiling turned on with the MPE library?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I am working on a free software application targeted at meteorologists and climate scientists called PIO: https://github.com/NCAR/ParallelIO.

As implied by the name it is a parallel I/O library using MPI.

I am trying to turn on profiling for the accompanying MPE library. There are lots of different documents on line that all mention the option -mpilog, but it's not clear where it should be used, or if something else should be used.

When I try adding -mpilog to either CC, CFLAGS, or LDFLAGS, configure fails with the message that the C compiler does not work.

So how do I turn on logging with MPE? I am using MPICH 3.2 on a Linux system.

Comment: Try `CC=mpecc CFLAGS=-mpilog configure ...`

Comment: Gilles Gouaillardet as stated it didn't work when I added it to CFLAGS:configure:3821: mpicc -g -Wall -mpilog -I/usr/local/netcdf-c-4.7.0_hdf5-1.10.5_mpich-3.2/include -I/usr/local/netcdf-fortran-4.4.5_c_4.6.3_mpich-3.2/include -I/usr/local/pnetcdf-1.11.0_shared/include -I/usr/local/gptl-all-1.0.0_mpich-3.2/include -I/usr/local/mpe2-2.4.9b/include -L/usr/local/netcdf-c-4.7.0_hdf5-1.10.5_mpich-3.2/lib -L/usr/local/pnetcdf-1.11.0_shared/lib -L/usr/local/gptl-all-1.0.0_mpich-3.2/lib -L/usr/local/mpe2-2.4.9b/lib conftest.c  >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mpilog'

Comment: and what if you use `mpecc` instead of `mpicc` ? (no, that was not a typo ...)

Comment: No, there is no mpecc.

Comment: are you should you installed all the MPE packages ? per https://github.com/pmodels/mpe and similar sources, `mpecc -mpilog ...` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this working, and here's how.

Firstly, thanks to Gilles Gouaillardet for pointing me at the MPE github site. There is a lot of old information out there about MPE, and it has changed a lot over the years, so reading about it on the GitHub site cleared up a lot of confusion.

For my PIO project, not only did I have to build PIO with MPE, but also HDF5, netcdf-c, and pnetcdf.

HDF5 was built like this:

```
CC='gcc' CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/local/zlib-1.2.11/include' LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/zlib-1.2.11/lib' LIBS='-llmpe -lmpe -lmpi -lpthread' ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/hdf5-1.10.5_mpe_static --disable-shared --enable-parallel
```

netCDF was built like this:

```
CC='gcc' CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/local/zlib-1.2.11/include -I/usr/local/hdf5-1.10.5_mpe_static/include' LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/zlib-1.2.11/lib -L/usr/local/hdf5-1.10.5_mpe_static/lib' ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/netcdf-c-4.7.0_hdf5-1.10.5_mpe_static_nodap --disable-shared --disable-dap
```

pnetcdf was built like this:

```
CC=gcc LIBS='-llmpe -lmpe -lmpi -lpthread' ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/pnetcdf-1.11.0_mpe --disable-shared --disable-cxx --disable-fortran
```

The PIO is built like this:

```
autoreconf -i && CC='gcc' CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/local/pnetcdf-1.11.0_mpe/include -I/usr/local/zlib-1.2.11/include -I/usr/local/hdf5-1.10.5_mpe_static/include -I/usr/local/netcdf-c-4.7.0_hdf5-1.10.5_mpe_static_nodap/include' LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/pnetcdf-1.11.0_mpe/lib -L/usr/local/zlib-1.2.11/lib -L/usr/local/hdf5-1.10.5_mpe_static/lib -L/usr/local/netcdf-c-4.7.0_hdf5-1.10.5_mpe_static_nodap/lib' LIBS=' -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lz -ldl -lm -llmpe -lmpe -lmpi -lpthread' ./configure --disable-shared --enable-mpe
```

Note that all the mpicc/mpecc compiler wrappers seemed unable to yield the correct results for this build, because the libraries would be listed in an incorrect order. Only by using CC=gcc, and explicitly linking to -llmpe -lmpe -lmpi -lpthread can this be made to build.

Once built, it gives very nice charts:
[image]